# How to install BurpAutoComplete Extension in Burp Suite

Tags: burp

In Burp Suite in Repeater Section , i want some thing that auto pop up me in term of header and etc
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSD8W.png)

1. Open cmd.
2. git clone https://github.com/Static-Flow/BurpSuiteAutoCompletion
3. Open the Eclipse and import the Git clone BurpAutoComplete Maven Project.
4. In Eclipse, Same Project Run As the Maven clean after that Run As the Maven install with Success success.
5. In Eclipse, Same Project Export >> Java > Jar >> by default Burpautocomplete is selected >> click on Finish then "burpautocomplete.jar" is created.
6. Open Buite Suite, Go to Extensions tab then in Burp extenion click on Add button >> In Load Burp Extension, Select thw Extension. Type as Java and Click on "Select file ..." >> select the jar file of burpautocomplete.jar. Click on Next then click on "Close" button.